# Need to cover string in test class

Tags: trigger, unit-test

Need to cover string in trigger.

Uncovered Part-

```
if(str.contains('Qty:') && str.contains('): $')){

    String pdQtyStr = (str.substringBetween('Qty:','): $')).trim();
    system.debug('pdQtyStr == '+pdQtyStr);
    if(pdQtyStr != null && pdQtyStr != '')
        payDetail.Add_Ons_Quantity__c = Integer.valueOf(pdQtyStr);
}else{                                      
    payDetail.Discount__c = pdi.Discount__c;
}
```

Comment: how are the value of str is calculated?

Comment: How have you tried to cover that, and why aren't you sure how to do it ? Your question still lacks critical information for us to know how to help you best.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to test with data that contains the strings in the if statement.

```
Qty:{x}): $
```

Where {x} can be anything.

Based on your edit, str is the Payment_Detail_Intermediate__c.Description__c field.

In your test class if you set the Description field of the PDI record you are performing DML on to the above string it should cover you code.